# Swift_TransportException Expected response code 220 but got an empty response

Tags: php, laravel, swiftmailer

My Laravel app was working fine. For some days the error shows up as

> Swift_TransportException
> Expected response code 220 but got an empty response

I'm using Hostinger Titan email

my configuration is

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.titan.email
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=class@techboxservices.com
MAIL_PASSWORD="***********"
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=class@techboxservices.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

The thing is that this works correctly in my localhost.

I have tried changing the configuration port,
deleted the email and created it again
but nothing works.

Comment: We need a proper stack trace. Open your `storage/logs/laravel.log` file and update your question with some details related to this error.

Comment: For future questions, you can change your actual email address to something obfuscated, too.